# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxhost: unable to open display ":0"

Tags: x11, display, x-server

Everytime i open a new console,the error info shown

[image]

[image]

```
xxd   ~/.Xauthority
00000000: 0100 0006 6465 6269 616e 0002 3130 0012  ....debian..10..
00000010: 4d49 542d 4d41 4749 432d 434f 4f4b 4945  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE
00000020: 2d31 0010 1fba cba8 1f6a f8b6 e00d 8c1a  -1.......j......
00000030: c7cb 7d86 0100 0006 6465 6269 616e 0001  ..}.....debian..
00000040: 3000 124d 4954 2d4d 4147 4943 2d43 4f4f  0..MIT-MAGIC-COO
00000050: 4b49 452d 3100 1050 f7f6 b85b 77e1 49e4  KIE-1..P...[w.I.
00000060: a0c6 470d 7b11 a9                        ..G.{..
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxhost: unable to open display ":0"
```

This is actually two error messages that have been printed out on the same line:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
xhost: unable to open display ":0"
```

When you log in using a X11 GUI, that session is automatically given a `DISPLAY` environment variable and a session-specific access key (stored either in `~/.Xauthority` or in a file specified by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable).

Console logins are separate from the GUI login, and so a console login session will not automatically get any of that. And you cannot use `xhost` to configure the access control of the GUI session unless you have access to the GUI session in the first place.

When a GUI session ends and a X11 server is restarted, a new session key is generated at the X11 server side, which automatically invalidates the previous key. But the old session key may be left in the user's `.Xauthority` file. It will automatically be replaced during the next GUI login. So the existence of a MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key in the `.Xauthority` file does not mean it's necessarily the *current* key.

If you run `pgrep -a Xorg`, you might see the command-line parameters of the X server process as something like `Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth <some path> <other options...>`. The path specified by the `-auth` option is the current server-side session key file: if you have root access, you can view it with e.g. `xauth -f <some path> list` and compare it to the contents of your own `.Xauthority` file, which is best viewed with `xauth list`. The output will be one or more lines like this:

```
debian/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  <actual key in hexadecimal>
```

The server-side key file should always have exactly 1 line, but if you have used SSH connections with X11 forwarding, you might have other lines in your own `.Xauthority` file, starting with e.g. `debian/unix:10` or higher display numbers.

If the `xauth list` output from your `.Xauthority` file includes a line that exactly matches the single line displayed by `xauth -f <some path> list`, you will be able to access the X server; if there is no matching line, the X server will reject your requests with an `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key` error.

I guess you may have a  `xhost` command in your `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or any similar login script. You should wrap it in a test that will test for the presence of the `$DISPLAY` variable before running `xhost`, so instead of e.g.:

```
xhost +local:
```

you would have e.g.

```
if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]
then
    xhost +local:
fi
```

But if the default location for the `~/.Xauthority` file is used, and you are doing this **only** to allow using GUI administration tools when using `sudo` to get root access, there might be a more secure way. Instead of adding `xhost +local:` (= allows everyone who e.g. SSHs into the same host access to your GUI session), you could add something like this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$SUDO_USER" != "" ] && [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]
then
    export XAUTHORITY=$(grep "^${SUDO_USER}:" /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 6)/.Xauthority
fi
```

Instead of relaxing the security on your GUI session, this uses the fact that root can read everything (so it won't work if your home directory is a NFS-mount that is exported with a `root_squash` option). When you are using `sudo`, it sets the `XAUTHORITY` variable to point directly to `.Xauthority` file in the home directory of your personal user account.

(Also, this trick does not work if you use `sudo su -`. Use `sudo -i` instead, and add a similar snippet to `/root/.bashrc` or `/root/.profile`. But be careful when editing those files: an unfortunate mistake could make it very difficult to get a working root shell again.)